# Test for statistically significant difference in means across different conditions

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, linear, group-differences

I've never had a formal statistics course, so I hope these questions aren't too basic or using incorrect terminology.

I have samples of bivariate data across different scales of 3 kinds, which I consider as different conditions, say T1, T2, T3,... D1, D2,D3,... and G1,G2,G3,... The explanatory variable takes on discrete values {1,2,3,...,n} and the response variable is between [0,1] $\subset \mathbb{R}$. I used nonlinear least squares to fit the data to a normal CDF and got estimates of mu and sigma.

Visually, there is a difference in the mean values across and among the conditions, i.e. among T1, T2, D1, D2, etc. and across T1 and D1, T1, and D3, etc. But I want to test for statistical significance in the difference, to be more confident in my findings. In the figure shown below, Nhrs, ngrams and the x-axis (11 points) are the different conditions over which the means ($\mu$) were estimated.

[image]

Due to the fact that the same algorithm is used to get the samples of bivariate data, I think they are not independent, can someone tells me whether this is correct?

Considering the aforementioned as true a paired t-test could work, for the response take on values from the same set [0,1], so paired differences makes sense. Nonetheless, what bothers me is that I'm not considering univariate data, so I'm not sure if the explanatory variable could have any effect here, other than serving as an index to subtract the correct pair of data.

I believe an easier way to assess the differences could be by linear regressions, e.g. test difference in constants to assess effects of condition G and test difference in slopes for condition D, but I'm not sure how to include the means' confidence intervals estimates to obtain estimates of the slope and constant for OLS, or even if using confidence intervals would be better at all.

Please, forgive any grammatical mistakes or awkwardly worded sentences; English is not my first language.